# Why can functions be constexpr even if they can't ever be used in a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

The `constexpr` specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time. The only use case for `constexpr` function is its ability to be resolved at compile time. Or to be more exact, the ability to initialize `constexpr` variable with its result. If you store result of `constexpr` function into `constexpr` variable, it forces the function to be pure (looks like it, not sure).

Why can the function `add` be marked `constexpr`?

```cpp
int global = 200;
constexpr int add(int a) {
    global += a; //works perfectly at run-time but no way to run at compile time
    return global;
}

int main() {
    // will not run since it attempts to access run-time storage,
    // global is not const and so on 
    constexpr int a = add(1);
    // works, but only at run-time, yet the function is constexpr
    int b = add(1);           
}
```

What is the use case for such function; why is it allowed at all?
A `constexpr` function can work with run time input since allowed to be used at run time.
However, what is the purpose to allow non-const runtime variables within function body that kill whole purpose of `constexpr`?

Does someone knows why standard allows such functions?

Comment: Iin a way a constexpr is a hint to the compiler that it may consider to run at compile time. use `consteval` (c++20) if a function MUST be evaluated at compile time. Also `int global=200;` is NOT a constant expression and can thus not be used at compile time. Use `static constexpr int global = 200;` And then you can use `static_assert(a == 201)` as second line in main

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the C++20 standard, [dcl.constexpr] p6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#6) (emphasis mine) Before C++23,

> For a constexpr function [...] that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function [...] could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression, [...], the program is ill-formed, **no diagnostic required**.

So no diagnostic is required.

Clang/gcc succeed to diagnose the issue [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vYrxPsKfa).

In C++23, it is now legal to have such function

> It is possible to write a constexpr function whose invocation can never satisfy the requirements of a core constant expression.

Rationale can be found in the paper [Relaxing some `constexpr` restrictions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2448r1.html).

Roughly, it is to be future-proof (in general case):
Functions not `constexpr` in version N might become `constexpr` in version N+1.

Comment: I've updated the question with a C++ standard citation instead of a cppreference quote. Cppreference is a community wiki, and prone to change, so citing it is not really future-proof. Feel free to roll back the change if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your question is: "Why is the function not rejected at definition but only when called in a constexpr context?"
Image your function looked like this:

```
int global = 200;
constexpr int add(int a) {
    if (a > 42) {
        global += a; 
        return global;
    }  
    return a;
}
```

This function can be evaluated at compile time for any argument less or equal than 42. Checking if the function can be evaluated at compile time for every possible input is a lot to ask of the compiler, so it is only required to happen when the function is actually called at compile time.

Comment: The question is about constexpr function body not its input.

Comment: @user10: but body validity might depends of function parameters. and in general case, it might be difficult or even impossible to know that.

Comment: Ignore my first comment I choose somewhat misleading example for what I wanted to ask.